# Countable partitions and law of total probability

Tags: probability-theory

In the statement of the law of total probability you assume that your partition $P$ of your sample space $\Omega$ is at most countable infinite.

What happens if your partition is not countable? Where does it fail? Is it possible to generalize it to an arbitrary partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma algebra. If $\{A_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ are a countable collection of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ then $\bigcup_{n\geq 0} A_n\in \mathcal{A}$ by definition and thus $P\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 0} A_n\right)$ is meaningful.

Instead, in general, the union of a non-countable set of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ does not belong to $\mathcal{A}$. For instance, consider $\Omega=[0,1]$, the usual Borel sigma-algebra and the Lebesgue measure. The sigma-algebra is not closed under non-countable unions, since otherwise every subset of $[0,1]$ would be measurable.